# ExpressionEngine not functioning properly after hosting transfer

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003, fastcgi, expressionengine

Just transferred an Expression Engine web site to a new hosting environment. New server is Windows 2003 Standard running PHP 5.2.44 via FastCGI and IIS 6. Other PHP sites run fine on this server (WordPress, CMSMadeSimple, etc.). This is the first ExpressionEngine site we've worked with. We've restored the database, setup a user account for it, and updated configuration settings in the encore_admin/config.php file. We tested database connectivity using the same information with MySQL Query Browser and there are no problems. Here is the URL so you can see the problems we are having:

http://encorellc.digitalaspire.com

http://encorellc.digitalaspire.com/encore_admin/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

not clear what problems you are having but you can try running their [server test](http://expressionengine.com/overview/requirements/), that should point out any server incompatibilities

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar issues.

Check out [this article](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Moving_Servers_-_A_Robust_Method/) about migrating servers - it may help you resolve issues.

If you're running into the same problem as me, the problem is generally paths, and string lengths stored in the EE database, particularly in the exp_sites table.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in your path.php and/or config.php are probably not filled out correctly